# Google Groups - "Don't Display at Top" nor "Delete" are working. How to get help from Google?

Tags: google-groups

I have several posts which are pinned to the top of my Google Group. For some reason when I click "Don't Display at Top" they temporarily seem unpinned until I reload the page... they instantly re-pin themselves.

So I thought, okay... I'm pretty fed up with this, so I'll just delete them.... nope, after deletion they magically re-appear on the next reload.

How can I contact Google to report an issue with Google Groups (not apps for work)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the related creature was retired. As of October 2023, according to [What's new in Groups](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/9718200?hl=en) **Pinning topics** (Making conversations appear at the top of the list) was deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

As of October 2023, Google Groups got again its Product Community. The link was taken from the Google Groups Help Center: https://support.google.com/groups/community

---

You can ask for help regarding Google Groups in the [Google Groups category](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/apps/google-groups-for-business) of the Google Apps for Work help forum, even if you are not using Google Groups for Business.